# disabled button

Tags: android

My problem: I wanna make an activity contains spinner and editBox & button I wanna make the button disabled until the user fill the box and choose an item from spinner. 
I wrote it check the if empty it disable the button but when i fill the box the button still disabled..!!the second problem : when I put hint into edite box it read it when check if the box is empty!! 
and how can I check the spinner if selected or not ??
*value is the name of editText
*enterBtn is the name of button.

```
    if(x.matches("")){
                enterBtn.setEnabled(false);
                 onStart();
            }else {
                enterBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            enterBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(Integer.valueOf(x)>(70)){
                Value.setText("plz dont enter more than 500");
                    }else{
........
...}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if the user has enetered more than 70 then telling them not to eneter more than 500?

Comment: ok it's a mistake thanx for the note but:) it doesnt effect into  code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Listener For Edit Box And Spinner..when you enters text to the Edit Text it Does not Check Whether It Has Text Entered Or not..thats why your button gets disabled..hear is the listner where you can actually get when someone entered text to Editext.

tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charCounts);

    textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

    textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            i++;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(i) + " / " + String.valueOf(charCounts));
        }

    });
```